# Primes dividing a sequence satisfying a linear recursion

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

Let $A_1, A_2, A_3, \dots$ be a sequence of integers. We say that the sequence is $C$-finite if it satisfies a linear recurrence

$$A_n = c_1A_{n-1}+c_2A_{n-2}+\dots+c_kA_{n-k}$$

for all $n$ past some point, where the $c_i$'s are fixed integers.  We say that a prime $p$ divides the sequence if there is some $n$ such that $p|A_n$. Morally the question I have is: Is every $C$-finite sequence divisible by infinitely many primes?

Of course, the answer to that question as stated is definitely 'No'. Any geometric sequence is $C$-finite and clearly has only finitely many prime divisors. Slightly more generally we have sequences like:

$$A_n = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       2^n & : n \in 2\mathbb{N} \\
       3^n & : n \notin 2\mathbb{N}
     \end{array}
   \right.$$

For which there exists some $m$ such that the sequence is geometric when restricted to any subsequence of $A_n$ consisting of those $n$ in a fixed congruence class mod $m$. We'll say that such sequences are *quasigeometric*, clearly such sequences also have finitely many prime divisors and it's not hard to show they are $C$-finite.

My actual question is: Is a $C$-finite sequence with finitely many prime divisors necessarily quasigeometric?

I'll note that it's true when $A_n$ is polynomial or quasipolynomial in $n$, if $A_n$ is the Fibonacci sequence, or if say $A_n = c^n-1$ for some integer $c$.

Comment: For  $F_n =A_{2^n} =  2^{2^n} + 1$, $(F_m, F_n)=1$, for $m\ne n$.  $(2^n + 3^n)_n$  not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well since I got no answer here, I decided to look into the literature a bit. For future reference (particularly my own) here's what I found:

The paper 'On a problem of Ward' by R. R. Laxton from 1974 shows that a slightly stronger assumption than not being quasigeometric implies infinitely many primes divide the sequence.

From there one can obtain the result for my weaker assumption without too much work by showing a non-quasigeometric sequence has a subsequence supported on an arithmetic progression which satisfies Laxton's stronger assumption, so the answer to my question is "yes".